# SDL Optimization 8 - Issue with loading Statistics in CMS

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.4, experience-optimization

I am facing issue with loading Statistics data into CMS, Experiment promotion showing fine on website, but when I see its statistics data in CMS it throws below error as shown in image below.

In managment service log shows the below error:

> 2017-01-31 12:36:22,299 ERROR ExperimentResolver - Unable to get a list of Experiments.
>   com.tridion.smarttarget.SmartTargetException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.AnalyticsManager.getStatistics(AnalyticsManager.java:215) ~[smarttarget_core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.AnalyticsManager.getStatistics(AnalyticsManager.java:189) ~[smarttarget_core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.experiments.Experiment.loadStatisticsPerDay(Experiment.java:151) ~[smarttarget_core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.sdl.web.experience.management.experiments.ExperimentResolver.getExperimentsWithStatistics(ExperimentResolver.java:154) ~[xo-management-extension-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.sdl.web.experience.management.experiments.ExperimentResolver.resolveCollection(ExperimentResolver.java:61) ~[xo-management-extension-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.sdl.web.content.odata.input.resolver.ResolverBase.resolve(ResolverBase.java:73) [content-v2-odata-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.sdl.web.content.odata.input.handler.ODataFeedRenderer.renderODataFeed(ODataFeedRenderer.java:57) [content-v2-odata-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.sdl.web.content.odata.input.handler.ODataWebHandler.handleODataEntity(ODataWebHandler.java:201) [content-v2-odata-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.sdl.web.content.odata.input.handler.ODataWebHandler.handleResourceRequest(ODataWebHandler.java:175) [content-v2-odata-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.sdl.web.content.controller.ContentV2Controller.handleResourceRequest(ContentV2Controller.java:91) [content-v2-controller-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at com.sdl.web.readwrite.filter.ReadWriteFilter.doFilter(ReadWriteFilter.java:67) [web-readwrite-filter-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:286) [web-ambient-client-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:68) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.StatisticsExecutor.getStatistics(StatisticsExecutor.java:47) ~[smarttarget_core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.AnalyticsManager.getStatistics(AnalyticsManager.java:213) ~[smarttarget_core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       ... 67 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191) ~[google-http-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127) ~[google-http-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:92) ~[google-http-client-jackson2.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85) ~[google-http-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81) ~[google-http-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:88) ~[google-oauth-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287) ~[google-oauth-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307) ~[google-oauth-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384) ~[google-api-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489) ~[google-oauth-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217) ~[google-oauth-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859) ~[google-http-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410) ~[google-api-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343) ~[google-api-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460) ~[google-api-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.google.GoogleAnalyticsQuery.execute(GoogleAnalyticsQuery.java:62) ~[smarttarget_google-analytics.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.google.GoogleAnalyticsManager.getStatisticsResults(GoogleAnalyticsManager.java:175) ~[smarttarget_google-analytics.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.StatisticsExecutor$StatisticsReader.call(StatisticsExecutor.java:113) ~[smarttarget_core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.StatisticsExecutor$StatisticsReader.call(StatisticsExecutor.java:59) ~[smarttarget_core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

Error Screen Shot from CMS.
[image]

Adding Error Logs of management Service in debug mode.

> 2017-03-10 15:26:00,435 DEBUG Triggers - Adding ScopeTrigger: SmartTarget Publication.
>   2017-03-10 15:26:00,435 DEBUG Triggers - Adding ScopeTrigger: SmartTarget Region.
>   2017-03-10 15:26:00,435 DEBUG Triggers - Adding ScopeTrigger: SmartTarget Page.
>   2017-03-10 15:26:00,435 DEBUG Triggers - Adding ScopeTrigger: SmartTarget Active Period.
>   2017-03-10 15:26:00,435 INFO  ExperimentResolver - Getting summary Statistics for Experiment: 5532a613-f139-4cf8-9d6a-090158cc003b
>   2017-03-10 15:26:00,435 INFO  ExperimentResolver - Getting summary Statistics for Experiment: 5532a613-f139-4cf8-9d6a-090158cc003b
>   2017-03-10 15:26:00,435 INFO  Experiment - Load summary statistics for Experiment: '5532a613-f139-4cf8-9d6a-090158cc003b'
>   2017-03-10 15:26:00,435 DEBUG AnalyticsManager - Instantiating analytics manager for configured class name: com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.google.GoogleAnalyticsManager
>   2017-03-10 15:26:00,498 DEBUG GoogleAnalyticsManager - Getting statistics from Google Analytics (viewId: ga:134475009, Start: 2017-01-23, End: 2017-01-24) for dimensions: 'ga:dimension8,ga:date,ga:eventAction', filtering on: 'ga:dimension1==5532a613-f139-4cf8-9d6a-090158cc003b;ga:dimension2==CdEnvironment2;ga:dimension3==tcm:0-5-1'.
>   2017-03-10 15:26:00,826 DEBUG GoogleAnalyticsManager - Getting statistics from Google Analytics (viewId: ga:134475009, Start: 2017-01-23, End: 2017-01-24) for dimensions: 'ga:dimension3,ga:dimension8,ga:eventAction', filtering on: 'ga:dimension1==5532a613-f139-4cf8-9d6a-090158cc003b;ga:dimension2==CdEnvironment2'.
>   2017-03-10 15:26:01,388 ERROR ExperimentResolver - Unable to get a list of Experiments.
>   com.tridion.smarttarget.SmartTargetException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.AnalyticsManager.getStatistics(AnalyticsManager.java:215) ~[smarttarget_core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.AnalyticsManager.getStatistics(AnalyticsManager.java:189) ~[smarttarget_core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.experiments.Experiment.loadStatistics(Experiment.java:198) ~[smarttarget_core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.sdl.web.experience.management.experiments.ExperimentResolver.getExperimentsWithStatistics(ExperimentResolver.java:159) ~[xo-management-extension-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.sdl.web.experience.management.experiments.ExperimentResolver.resolveCollection(ExperimentResolver.java:61) ~[xo-management-extension-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.sdl.web.content.odata.input.resolver.ResolverBase.resolve(ResolverBase.java:73) [content-v2-odata-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.sdl.web.content.odata.input.handler.ODataFeedRenderer.renderODataFeed(ODataFeedRenderer.java:57) [content-v2-odata-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.sdl.web.content.odata.input.handler.ODataWebHandler.handleODataEntity(ODataWebHandler.java:201) [content-v2-odata-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.sdl.web.content.odata.input.handler.ODataWebHandler.handleResourceRequest(ODataWebHandler.java:175) [content-v2-odata-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.sdl.web.content.controller.ContentV2Controller.handleResourceRequest(ContentV2Controller.java:91) [content-v2-controller-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at com.sdl.web.readwrite.filter.ReadWriteFilter.doFilter(ReadWriteFilter.java:67) [web-readwrite-filter-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:286) [web-ambient-client-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:68) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.StatisticsExecutor.getStatistics(StatisticsExecutor.java:47) ~[smarttarget_core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.AnalyticsManager.getStatistics(AnalyticsManager.java:213) ~[smarttarget_core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       ... 68 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191) ~[google-http-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127) ~[google-http-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:92) ~[google-http-client-jackson2.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85) ~[google-http-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81) ~[google-http-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:88) ~[google-oauth-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287) ~[google-oauth-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307) ~[google-oauth-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384) ~[google-api-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489) ~[google-oauth-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217) ~[google-oauth-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859) ~[google-http-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410) ~[google-api-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343) ~[google-api-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460) ~[google-api-client.jar:1.19.0]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.google.GoogleAnalyticsQuery.execute(GoogleAnalyticsQuery.java:62) ~[smarttarget_google-analytics.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.google.GoogleAnalyticsManager.getStatisticsResults(GoogleAnalyticsManager.java:175) ~[smarttarget_google-analytics.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.StatisticsExecutor$StatisticsReader.call(StatisticsExecutor.java:113) ~[smarttarget_core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.StatisticsExecutor$StatisticsReader.call(StatisticsExecutor.java:59) ~[smarttarget_core-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
>       ... 1 common frames omitted

Adding smarttarget_conf.xml file analytics section:

> ```
>     <Analytics implementationClass="com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.google.GoogleAnalyticsManager" timeoutMilliseconds="5000" trackingRedirectUrl="/redirect/">
>         <ServiceAccountEmailAddress>***</ServiceAccountEmailAddress>
>         <PrivatekeyPath>***</PrivatekeyPath>
>         <AccountId>**</AccountId>
>         <TrackingId>***</TrackingId>
>         <ViewId>13447***</ViewId>
>         <CustomDimensions>
>             <ExperimentId>dimension1</ExperimentId>
>             <InstanceId>dimension2</InstanceId>
>             <PublicationId>dimension3</PublicationId>
>             <PageId>dimension4</PageId>
>             <Region>dimension5</Region>
>             <ComponentId>dimension6</ComponentId>
>             <ComponentTemplateId>dimension7</ComponentTemplateId>
>             <ChosenVariant>dimension8</ChosenVariant>
>         </CustomDimensions>
>     </Analytics>
> ```

I am using DXA 1.4 with SDL Optimization tool.

Please help to resolve this issue, may be I have miss some configuration settings.

Thanks
Piyush Jain

Comment: Please help on this !!! I am not getting any clue why this error occurred!!!

Comment: Still not able to get any clue on this. any Suggestion?

Comment: Were you able to log a support ticket on this? Tridion Stack Exchange is a good place to ask questions about software behavior, code, configuration, and issues; but Support is in the best position to resolve things for customers, especially when the community doesn't respond on a given question. I can help by offering points for a bounty for visibility, though.

Comment: Have you confirmed you OAuth2 configuration (seeing _com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:88) ~[google-oauth-client.jar:1.19.0]_ )

Is there anything additional in the event logs?

Comment: Please update your question with information on what you have tried. It's been weeks so you must have something to share :)
Also please include the analytics part of the smarttarget_conf.xml file in your management service (but  replace all sensitive information with placeholders first!)

Answer (score 1):

at first glance it looks like SmartTarget is working fine (content is being delivered from FH) but there is a failing in communication between SmartTarget and Google Analytics.  My first thought is to check whether you have all the necessary jars in the correct places.  Please check the jars in the Publication Target's CD Endpoint URL as follows:

[image]

Ensure you have the following:

```
 All Google Analytics provider jars to lib
 All Content Delivery jars to lib
 SmartTarget API Web Serivce jar to lib
 All Ambient Data Framework jars to lib
 Content Delivery dotNet DLLs to bin
```

Comment: I am Using SDL Web 8 with all Micro services. , It seems all jars Files are in Place, Still the same result. Also adding management Service logs in debug mode.